# Start activity when return of background

Tags: android

I need that when my app goes to the background and come back to the foreground ever return to specific activity. 
For example my app has the activities A,B and C, if the user is on activity B or C and put the app on background, when return to the app the app must return to foreground on activity A, ever return on activity A. Is it possible?

Comment: May be `finish()` in `onPause()`?

Comment: use finish() inside the onResume()

Comment: Is activity A always the first activity in the stack (like a Home Activity)? And also, do you want B and C to be destroyed in this case you mentioned?

Comment: Yes, B and C must be detroyed when the go to background and return everytime on activity A. Is it possible? If I put finish inside the onResume() like Vaudey suggest, automatically my app return on Activiy A?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

I use in manifests the tag android:noHistory="true". And when the app come back to the foreground I use onResume() to validate conection.

Thanks  jaibatrik,  Vaudey Baptiste and  GingerNinja23 by help me.